# Using Anywhere on Earth time zone in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I'm taking classes online, and they allow us to submit our projects on a given date, up to midnight Anywhere on Earth.

Turns out Anywhere on Earth is an actual time zone where Baker and Howland islands in the Pacific Ocean reside. It's UTC/GMT -12.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth
http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/aoe

I want to set up Google Calendar appointments for that time zone so I can make sure my project submissions aren't late, but I don't see that timezone listed anywhere. The closest one I have found is "U.S. Outlying Islands/Pogo Pogo", but that's UTC -11.

Is there a time zone that's UTC -12 that I've missed, or is there any way to specify the UTC offset in Google Calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a UTC-12 time a zone in Google Calendar and there isn't a way to specify the UTC offset in the Google Calendar web app.

From [Anywhere on Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anywhere_on_Earth)

> Note that the day's end AOE occurs at noon [Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)
>   (UTC) of the following day, [Howland Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howland_Island) being halfway around the
>   world from the [Prime Meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Meridian) that is the base reference longitude for
>   UTC.